# strongloop installation on windows 10, visual studio community 2015

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, strongloop

I have following environment

```
**OS**: Windows 10
**Visual Studio** : 2015 community edition
**NodeJS** : v0.12.0
**Python** : 2.7.10
```

I am trying to install, [strongloop](https://strongloop.com) with following command.

```
npm install -g strongloop
```

Unfortunately, it is failing with following error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(344,5):
warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.
TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version
number. [C:\Users\xxx\App Data\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\heapdump\build\addon.vcxproj]
heapdump.cc
c:\users\xxx\.node-gyp\0.12.0\deps\v8\include\v8stdint.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory
[C:\users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\heapdump\build\addon.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-supervisor\node_modules\heapdump
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I tried installing using an alternative command as

```
npm install -g strongloop --msvs_version=2015
```

But that too failed with following error.

```
customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
**(More stack trace)** 
versions = _DetectVisualStudioVersions(version_map[version], 'e' in version)
KeyError: '2015'
```

I couldn't find much information about this problem and almost stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with the old version of Node and node-gyp you are using: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/555

This may also be relevant: http://www.serverpals.com/blog/building-using-node-gyp-with-visual-studio-express-2015-on-windows-10-pro-x64

If you are stuck on v0.12, you should at least upgrade to v0.12.7, otherwise I highly recommend upgrading to the latest LTS release from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ (v4.2.1 at the moment).